# How to sum up and get totals of all numeric values in one column in android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So i have created and filled my database table,displayed data using custom adapter in an activity.I have tried to add the values of one column "amount" and getting the total displayed in an activity.After research,this is what i found suited my goal:

```
public int getTotalOfAmount(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount)FROM"+CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int i=c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
        return i;
    }
```

And displaying in my activity as:

```
TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Amount_textView);
int i=myDb.getTotalOfAmount();
txt2.setText(""+i);
```

However on running the app,it crashes when the activity is started with the following logcat error:

```
04-14 13:14:13.513    9231-9231/com.snappy.stevekamau.cosmeticsapp E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: amount
04-14 13:14:13.603    9231-9231/com.snappy.stevekamau.cosmeticsapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e83438)
```

Now i dont know what is happening here because i do have this column `CONTACTS_COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";`in my table.From what i understand,there must be something i have missed on my code.

Complete **DBHelper.java:**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
    public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESC = "description";

    private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table contacts " +
                        "(id integer primary key, title text,amount text,description text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertContact(String title, String amount, String description) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("title", title);
        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("description", description);


        db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts where id=" + id + "", null);
        return res;
    }

    public int numberOfRows() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int cnt = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return cnt;
    }

    public boolean updateContact(Integer id, String title, String amount, String description) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("title", title);
        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("description", description);

        db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
        return true;
    }

    public void deleteContact() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("contacts", null, null);
        db.close();
    }
    public void deleteSingleContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID+"="+id,null);

           }


    public boolean checkForTables() {
        boolean hasRows = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int count = cursor.getInt(0);
        if(count > 0)
            hasRows = true;
        db.close();
        return hasRows;
    }
    public int getTotalOfAmount(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount)FROM"+CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int i=c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
        return i;
    }

    public ArrayList<ContactListItems> getAllContacts() {
        ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
                ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();

                contactListItems.setTitle(res.getString(res
                        .getColumnIndex("title")));
                contactListItems.setAmount(res.getString(res
                        .getColumnIndex("amount")));
                contactListItems.setDescription(res.getString(res
                        .getColumnIndex("description")));
                contactList.add( contactListItems);
                res.moveToNext();
            }
        res.close();
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

**To Note:** Also i should add that the Amount column is a string input type,i am not sure if it should be an integer for the above method to work??Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: your Query is working fine in SQLite browser.? Please check it.

Comment: please uninstall your app and reinstall or upgrade your database version ,because may be you added that coloumn after creating the database

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you should be using the static variables for column names in your code instead of hardcoding them each time. First you will avoid typos, second it's easier to update column names for instance.

Comment: you should change your amount type to float to achieve this

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways. Here is one of them way

```
      int count=0;

      Cursor c=null;
        try{
             c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT amount FROM contacts" , null);

            if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    String totalAmt = c.getString(0);
                    count+=Integer.valueOf(totalAmt);

                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            c.close();

        }finally{
            c.close();
        }

        System.out.println("total amount: "+count);
```

Comment: That has solved the crash issue Thanks!!!But still the total is 0.Any work around for that?

Comment: @SteveKamau Check that you have amount values in your table.

Comment: @MD your solution will not work since the data type of amount was set to text

Comment: @GowthamRaj And before comment check my answer description please. I already told you **Many Ways to Achieve this**

Comment: @MD this is how i insert the values in my table

Comment: `if (mydb.insertContact(title.getText().toString(), amount.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString())) {
                    showAlertDialog();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } `

Comment: My amount text like i said is a string that cntains numeric and text for example: **Ksh.120** ,if i do change the data type to decimal/real it will cause problems.please advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount)FROM"+CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME,null);
```

You are just missing the space after FROM.

(Without the space, `FROMcontacts` is interpreted as an alias name for the output column.)

Comment: Thanks!!This was answered above.There is another issue of the code not really working

Answer (score 1):

The first problem in your table is the datatype of `amount` is `text` which cannot be summed up the ideal way to store the values (which should be in `decimal` / `real` format from the start), however you could do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(SUBSTR(amount, 2) as decimal) FROM record
```

The `SUBSTR` method is a text function that will take a section of the text (in this case, from a starting index).

This should now work as SQLLite allows for [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) (which in a nutshell, means that the value is used for comparison, not the container).

**Possible solutions to your problem:**
Either change the data type of the table or change the select query

Comment: when yu say change my select query,i have used your example and the result is still the same 0.

Comment: ,Like i have explained above,i am getting some text that is displayed to string and inserting to data base.i am stuck at changing the datatype from string as it may not work.

Comment: what kind of input will u get in amount field.... is it like $5.00 or just 5.00 or just 5 ..

Comment: It is like $5.00 ,both text and numerical value

Comment: I have edited the query try it.. and tell me the result

Comment: and small advise it is not good to store the decimal values as string in your table instead u can store as value in one column and the type of currency in the other column depending on the currency column append the symbol in your code this will prevent lot of conversion jobs.

Comment: i decided to take your advice and changed all references of amount to integer.Howver at the following code where i am taking a text lets say 100 and inserting it into database,i am not sure how to handle it.I have tried changing the string to integer but its not working.

Comment: if (mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update, title.getText().toString(), amount.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString()))

Comment: where-->amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount_label); amount.setText(rate);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75311/discussion-between-gowtham-raj-and-steve-kamau).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have column named **amount** but the type of amount is **text** and I dont think you will get desired result by applying **sum** function to data of type text.

you can try out this piece of code:

```
public int getTotalOfAmount() {
    int sum = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT amount FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
    }
    c.close();
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: like i have exlained above,my data type contains both text and numerical value,is there a work around?Because on my first activity where i am displaying some text,the displayed text is put to string and saved to data base.Which is why changing the data type is a challenging task

Comment: Please check my comments above